# What is the number inside the parenthesis on a Linux command?

Tags: shell, command-line, terminal, posix

What is `1`? What is `3`? What are the numbers called and is there a full list with explanations?

```bash
$ whatis nvim
nvim (1)             - edit text

$ whatis printf
printf (3)           - formatted output conversion
printf (1)           - format and print data
```

---

---

Thanks :)

Comment: Those are parentheses, not brackets.

Comment: @RonJohn oh yeah you are right. My bad, was tired when I wrote that question ^^

Comment: No need to be mean an downvote, I think, so +1.

Comment: @RonJohn Americans say 'parenthesis', but the British say 'round bracket'

Comment: @j4nd3r53n thank you very much^^ Yeah `Stack Overflow` is a very toxic place, but on this question I can kinda understand it. The problem is I didn't even know what to search the internet for, because I didn't know the name of it. But of course it is a duplicate, still thanks for being kind :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is section numbers, according to `man man`:

> The table below shows the section numbers of the  manual  followed  by the types of pages they contain.
>
> 1   Executable programs or shell commands
> 2   System calls (functions provided by the kernel)
> 3   Library calls (functions within program libraries)
> 4   Special files (usually found in /dev)
> 5   File formats and conventions, e.g. /etc/passwd
> 6   Games
> 7   Miscellaneous  (including  macro  packages  and conventions), e.g.
> man(7), groff(7), man-pages(7)
> 8   System administration commands (usually only for root)
> 9   Kernel routines [Non standard]

Ex:

```
man 3 printf # C Linux Programmer's Manual
man 1 printf # User Commands
```

`man -k printf`

```
[...]
sprintf (3)          - formatted output conversion
swprintf (3)         - formatted wide-character output conversion
vasprintf (3)        - print to allocated string
[...]
```